# How to avoid lint problem "Depend on referenced packages" for gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart

Tags: flutter, dart, lint

On my Flutter app, I've got this problem with lint rule : [depend_on_referenced_packages](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/depend_on_referenced_packages.html)

[image]

This file is generated here

[image]

Do you have any idea how to solve this without passing by ignore 'depend_on_referenced_packages' ?

in my pubspec.yaml, I only have this :

[image]

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just add the package explicitly.

1. run `flutter pub add flutter_gen`
2. run `flutter pub get`

For more info, see https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/depend_on_referenced_packages.html

Comment: This works. And I really like this sollution since it solves the problem instead of just hiding the error. But I'm still wondering what causes the lint?

Comment: @AymenDn Firstly, _refenrenced packages_ are packages referenced by other packages you explicitly depend on, as shown in `pubspec.yaml`. It works without explicitly importing because these packages are also cached, but it's hard to know the package's information, e.g., versions you're using. Hence, they recommend doing this explicitly.

Comment: I happen to have this issue just now. For me, I accidentally deleted the `dependencies:` line in my **pubspec.yaml** file. Simply restoring that got things back to normal.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know how to ignore only generated packages, but this is how you turn off the rule entirely:

1. Create a file `analysis_options.yaml` in your project root.
2. Paste this:

```
include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml

linter:
  rules:
    depend_on_referenced_packages: false
```

Additional information about this file can be found at https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options

Comment: Though I would generally recommend to leave this `true` and add an explicit dependency on the referenced package.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#adding-your-own-localized-messages), it seems that just having a dependency on `flutter_localizations` only is not enough. Your dependencies should look like this:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.17.0 # Add this line
```

Comment: I've already added all this on my pubspec but i still have the problem depend_on_referenced_packages

Answer (score 4):

For me, this error occurs because I accidentally put my package name in the dev_dependencies section. Putting my package name in dependencies section fixed my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using `collection.dart` more than a dozen places in my app and recently after the Flutter 3.0 upgrade this lint started to pop up for me. I think `depend_on_referenced_packages` is a really useful lint to warn you about unnecessary imports. I would never turn it off entirely for the project (@EzPizza's answer).

You can suppress the lint for an affected file by adding this comment to the file:

`// ignore_for_file: depend_on_referenced_packages`

But it's even better to fix the root cause of the problem and include the indicated dependencies into your `pubspec.yaml`. Like for example what @mkobuolys proposes.

Answer (score 3):

For me, I **accidentally** put the package `url_launcher: ^6.1.7` under `dev_dependencies:`

**Solution:**

I **removed** the package from `dev_dependencies` and **added** it below `dependencies:`

Answer (score 0):

I'm only posting this because the other answers either didn't help me or I didn't understand them.

I got the same warning on a different package, namely page_transition. Here's what I found on why the problem occurs:

> When importing a package, add a dependency on it to your pubspec.
>
> Depending explicitly on packages that you reference **ensures they will always exist and allows you to put a dependency constraint on them to guard you against breaking changes.**

Meaning you are right to look for a solution other than to ignore it.

Here's how I fixed it:
I went to pubspec.yaml and added the following under dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  page_transition: ^2.0.9
```

You can add the dependency for your package which you would have to look up. I just googled "flutter app_localizations" and this came up, you can see the latest version under the **Installing** tab.
[localization 2.1.0](https://pub.dev/packages/localization/install)

So, if you're using that package, as an example, you would have to add

```
dependencies:
  localization: ^2.1.0
```

Answer (score -1):

for me it was because the packages i was having this warning on didn't support flutter 3 yet.

Answer (score -1):

this is [the official link](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/depend_on_referenced_packages.html)

you should direct dependency not indirectly dependency.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32102227)